# Laravel nested eager loading specific columns in where condition in main relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eager

```
$wo = Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with('item_info.product_sub_group')
    ->where('item_info.product_sub_group->sub_group_id', 2)
    ->get();
```

How to select specific column after relationship in where condition?

Comment: you need to condition by specific column or select only a specific column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can condition the relation using `with()`

```php
$wo = Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with(['item_info.product_sub_group' => function($productSubGroup) {
        $productSubGroup->where('sub_group_id', '=', 2);
    }])
    ->get();
```

If you want only the `Warehouse_other_receive_detail` that have `product_sub_group->sub_group_id = 2` use `having()`

```php
$wo = Warehouse_other_receive_detail::having('item_info.product_sub_group', function($productSubGroup) {
        $productSubGroup->where('sub_group_id', '=', 2);
    })
    ->with(['item_info.product_sub_group' => function($productSubGroup) {
        $productSubGroup->where('sub_group_id', '=', 2);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: How I will access specific column in main query ( such as on model Warehouse_other_receive_detail) .